# Receiving error when using push_back with a struct data type c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code, where I am generating a deck of cards.
First, I determine the suit with the function convertIntToSuit, which then goes into the next loop to populate the Card deck. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/A5/Assignment5/main.cpp
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/workspace/A5/Assignment5'
Compiling main.o
g++ -Wall -g -O3 -std=c++11 -I/usr/include -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:39:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Card>::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
             deck.push_back({i,s});
```

Here is my code:

```
// The include section adds extra definitions from the C++ standard library.
#include <iostream> // For cin, cout, etc.
#include <iomanip>  // For text formatting (setprecision, setw, etc.)
#include <cmath>    // For math functions (sin, cos, pow, etc.)
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

#include"convertIntToSuit.h"
#include"printCard.h"
//#include"shuffleDeck.h"

using namespace std;

struct Card {
    string suit;
    int rank;
};

int main() {
    vector<Card> deck;
    for(int j = 0; j<4; ++j){
        string s = convertIntToSuit(j);
        for(int i=1; i<=13; ++i){
            deck.push_back({i,s});
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The first value in the braced initialization list is an integer, the second is a string. Now keep staring at your `Card` class, until you see your own bug.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had switched those, but I guess not

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this for every iteration:-

```
Card c1;
c1.suit=s;
c1.rank=i
deck.push_back(c1);
```

***Or***

what you are doing will be:-

```
deck.push_back({s,i});
```

`string` will come first before `int` because of your `struct declaration`.

Comment: Is there any difference between `deck.push_back({s,i}); ` and `deck.push_back(Card{s,i});`?

Answer (score 0):

The `push_back` function does not understand what you are sending to it. Enclosing the two properties of `Card` in curly brackets is not enough. You must construct the `Card` struct before sending it to push_back.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options here:

1. Either to construct Card object explicitly: `deck.push_back(Card{s,i});`
2. Construct card object in-place inside vector. That could eliminate unneeded object copies though in this case the benefit is negligible. But for that you need to define an explicit c'tor that takes both arguments.
   c++11 does not allow implicit construction of objects with just arguments. 
   Once you have the c'tor - you can use [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) member function which does exactly what you want: it takes the arguments to the constructor and constructs the object in-place with those arguments. In your case:

   ```
    struct Card {
       string suit;
       int rank;
       Card(string s = string(), int r = 0) : suit(std::move(s)), rank(r) {}
    };

    for (int i=1; i<=13; ++i){
      deck.emplace_back(i,s);
    }
   ```

Please note that you do not need curly brackets when using `emplace_back`.